# Change location and size of boot partition ubuntu 16

Tags: boot, 16.04, bios

background:

Ive been taking advantage of some cheap deals on old dell r410s on ebay. I want to boot them with Ubuntu 16 desktop with a 12tb raid 0 array. I keep getting grub errors:

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'. 
Entering rescue mode... 
grub rescue>
```

All of the forms I have come across suggest reinstalling grub, or remounting the partition - non of which work. However, if I delete the raid array, and reinstall ubuntu on just one of the hdds, it boots fine. I think this is related to an underlying bios issue, where booting from a huge partition causes problems. These servers all have bios 1.12.0. The solution for this is to simply create a small, 150gb, boot partition and move this partition to the beginning of the overall raid array... or so I have been told.

Question:

Once I setup the raid array, I have to reinstall ubuntu, and then reboot. However, now I cant boot ubuntu to create a small boot partition and move it to the front of the larger partition. Basically, my question is how do I do this?

Secondarily, let me know if this is a stupid idea. I am still troubling shooting my original error, and I would appreciate any advice on the topic.

Comment: Does it recognizes the array ina live session? If so it supports the controller. I's just a matter of partitioning in advance and create a separated `/boot` at the beginning of the drive, *within* the first 100 or so GB (yes, a BIOS limitation) but not as huge, not even close. It's for kernels only and typical is a few hundreds MB.

Comment: It recognizes the array. As you suggest, it is the bios limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is a little obvious in hind sight.

1. I began by creating the raid array
2. installed ubuntu 16
3. rebooted using the live usb
4. selected "try" ubuntu, and went through the boot repair options detailed here:
   https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/
5. Then followed the boot partition guidelines here:
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition
6. reboot

For reference, step 5 is the answer to my question, while steps 1-6 took care of my general problem.

It booted just fine. Hopefully this helps others with similar issues.